# Generate Spectrogram with SoX

Tags: sox

I'm trying to generate a spectrogram using the [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/Main/HomePage) program. According to the [documentation](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html), I should try the following to create a spectrogram:

```
sox output.wav -n spectrogram
```

Instead of a spectrogram I get the following error:

```
sox FAIL formats: can't determine type of `spectrogram'
```

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me. You're sure you have an `output.wav` file, and that's exactly what you're typing? (also, I think this question is better suited for superuser)

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: (Arch) Linux. I also have sox version 14.4.1. What version are you using?

Comment: 14.4.1 also. I just installed it on os x, and seems to be working fine. I'm going to try a fresh install.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for confirming it was working on your system :)

Answer (score 7):

I know why it happened. You copied this text-command from documentation http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html So, if you type manually it will work fine. Some symbols in documentation are in incorrect charset for you

Answer (score 2):

To amplify [Dima Melnik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499722/generate-spectrogram-with-sox/29447945#29447945)'s answer, the online manual has substituted Unicode characters where ASCII is expected. If you copy the [spectrogram](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html) example verbatim, the `-n` (bytes \x2d \x6e) you think you're typing are actually `−n` (bytes \xe2 \x88 \x92 \x6e, first character U+2212 *MINUS SIGN* in UTF-8). `sox` is trying to parse`−n` as a file name, and is getting confused.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when i built SoX on my own. The lack of libpng created a binary without spectrogram effect. In other words, your command is trying to open a file named "spectrogram". Run

> sox -h

and check the if you have this effect.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do it,

```sh
sox output.wav -n spectrogram
```